# Lookup time for std::unordered_set not constant

Tags: c++, microbenchmark, unordered-set

For figuring out the best container type for my specific purpose, I was comparing lookup times of std::vector, sorted std::vector with binary search, std::set and std::unordered_set. Here are the results:

[image: Lookup Time Comparison]

I skipped std::vector lookup for more than 10'000 elements to keep the runtime finite. The containers are filled with all integers from 0 to n-1 and the lookup is performed for 100'000 random integers.

No big surprises about the vectors and the ordered set there, but what is happening with std::unordered_set? The lookup time is supposed to be constant there... Some fluctuation probably is to be expected due to rehashing at certain thresholds and such, but the rise after 300'000 elements looks very strange to me. Does somebody have an explanation?

The code was compiled and run on linux with GCC 11.3.0 in release mode (with O3 I think).

EDIT:

I have done more testing:

[image: Lookup Comparison 2]

Here I call rehash(n*4) after the construction of the unordered_set. So the average amount of collisions and the length of the lists in the buckets should be constant. Caching could be an explanation but then I would not expect the lookup time to continue increasing.

EDIT2:

I did more tests and also used a higher resolution now. First I tested if 10x as many buckets (but the same amount of elements) cause the bump to happen at 1/10th the number of elements:

[image: 10x as many buckets]

But then I figured if linked lists are involved, it's probably more about the actual amount of stored data. So I did another test:

Here I have unordered_sets of arrays of ints. One int and ten ints. Hashing and operator== only use the first array element. If the slowdown is due to caching, my expectation would again be to see the bump for the 10 ints set at 1/10th of the number of elements compared to the 1 int set. But maybe it's not that simple. But I think it should be that simple...

[image: lookup int1 and ints10]

EDIT3:

Now I moved the rand call out of the time measurements, the speedup is much larger than I expected (I actually thought it would cause many more cache misses due to alternating lookups in the rand vector and the set but that's maybe not how caches work).

[image]

Here is the benchmark code that ChatGPT and I wrote:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// Custom binary search implementation
bool binarySearch(const std::vector<int>& vec, int target) {
    int left = 0, right = vec.size() - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (vec[mid] == target) {
            return true;
        } else if (vec[mid] < target) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void testLookupTime(int n, int k) {
    std::cout << "[" << n << ", ";

    // Generate test data
    std::vector<int> testData(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        testData[i] = i;
    }

    // Seed for random number generation
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    if(n < 1e4){
        // Test std::vector lookup time
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            int randomNum = std::rand() % (n + 1);
            volatile std::vector<int>::iterator result = std::find(testData.begin(), testData.end(), randomNum);
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << ", ";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "0, ";
    }

    // Test sorted std::vector with binary search lookup time
    std::sort(testData.begin(), testData.end());
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        int randomNum = std::rand() % (n + 1);
        volatile bool result = binarySearch(testData, randomNum);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << ", ";

    // Test std::set lookup time
    std::set<int> testSet(testData.begin(), testData.end());
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        int randomNum = std::rand() % (n + 1);
        volatile std::set<int>::iterator result = testSet.find(randomNum);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << ", ";

    // Test std::unordered_set lookup time
    std::unordered_set<int> testUnorderedSet(testData.begin(), testData.end());
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        int randomNum = std::rand() % (n + 1);
        volatile std::unordered_set<int>::iterator result = testUnorderedSet.find(randomNum);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << "],\n" << std::flush;
}

int main() {
    const int kTimes = 100000;

    for(float n=5; n<=1e8; n*=1.1){
        testLookupTime(n, kTimes);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::unordered_set` is implemented as a linked list.  As the buckets fill up the links grow and access time increases.

Comment: The C++ unordered associative containers, like `std::unordered_set`, are implemented as separate-chaining hash tables, which can have a fast performance degradation.

Comment: After collision, something similar to a link-list is used...

Comment: *Custom binary search* Why not use `std::binary_search()`?

Comment: You're looking for different numbers in every collection. For a fair comparison, generate the numbers to look up first. (And `std::rand` is terrible, as is using `%` for the range.)

Comment: The code is wrong: `volatile` usage is wrong, `testLookupTime()` lookups same values withing a second interval.

Comment: The datastructure should indeed have O(1) Search, insertion, and removal. However at some point you will also start noticing cache behavior of your system. Which seems to happen at around 10^5-10^6  elements (up till then it is pretty constant).

Comment: @273 Hypothetically volatile might be correct to force a read or write for testing. But that's for OP to comment on ;)

Comment: @OP I also advice you to not use inline timing (and specialy not with high_resolution_clock, which may map on std::system_clock). I find using a benchmark library (or a profiler) give more reliable results. You might have a look at : https://nanobench.ankerl.com/. Also not a profiler will actually show you will have branch prediction misses and cache misses which will impact performance a lot too

Comment: `unordered_set` is not nearly as cache-friendly as `vector` is.  I.e. the data does not all lie in consecutive memory in `unordered_set`.  It is scattered around the address space.

Comment: In your custom binary search function you're doing two comparisons per iteration whereas only one is enough.

Comment: `Constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container.`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find

Comment: Addressing all: I think I have shown that it's not about the linked list. I use a custom binary search because ChatGPT spit that out, can certainly be optimized. I moved the rand out of the loop in the last plot, didn't change the issue. I use volatile so the result doesn't get optimized away. Timing is on the order of seconds, system_clock should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find states:

> Constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container

Finding the bucket containing an object should always be constant time (subject to CPU effects like caching etc.) but finding an object inside a bucket depends on the number of objects in that bucket.

As the container fills up and there are multiple objects in each bucket, lookup time will increase.

You could decrease the load factor if you want to maintain linear or near-linear lookup performance though this will decrease insert performance due to more frequent re-hashing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/max_load_factor

Comment: This describes the cause of volatility in timings for smaller sets, it doesn't explain the slow but steady increase in time for the larger sets (which is almost certainly caching effects). For random integers, the "worst case linear" situation should basically never occur, and as the container size increases, the number of buckets should expand, so it wouldn't show a slowing trend, just a little variability as it gets slower until the load factor is reached, then faster when it rehashes and the number of bucket collisions goes back down.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually measuring the performance of `std::rand`.

Here's a stripped-down version of your test that moves the random lookup generation out of the timing loop, and it does not show the same growth in lookup time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void testLookupTime(int n, int k) {
    std::cout << "[" << n << ", ";

    // Generate test data
    std::vector<int> testData(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        testData[i] = i;
    }

    std::vector<int> lookups(k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        lookups[i] = std::rand() % (n + 1);
    }

    // Added just to make sure the unordered_set::find isn't getting optomized out
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        // no-op
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << ", ";

    // Test std::unordered_set lookup time
    std::unordered_set<int> testUnorderedSet(testData.begin(), testData.end());
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        volatile std::unordered_set<int>::iterator result = testUnorderedSet.find(lookups[k]);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() << "],\n" << std::flush;
}

int main() {
    // Seed for random number generation
    std::srand(std::time(0));    
    
    const int kTimes = 100000;

    for(float n=1e6; n<=1e7; n*=1.15){
        testLookupTime(n, kTimes);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99793d3d432ae0c5)

Note: I had to tweak the range of container sizes to get the program to finish within the allotted time on coliru, but it shows constant lookup times over the whole original range of inputs on my local machine.

Comment: I appended another plot. Moving rand out of the measurement speeds things up but the overall issue clearly remains.

Comment: Odd, I get [very different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zfjJ.png) from what you're seeing.  With `rand` in the loop I get somewhat similar slow growth, but without `rand` not in the loop the lookup times are constant.

Comment: Can you use log axes both for x and y?

Comment: Here's the plot using log scales: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1yGH.png.

Comment: That is super odd. Why would std::rand introduce such a curve? It should not depend on the number of elements at all...

Comment: Now I'm even less sure what's going on.  I moved the tests out into their own functions, and now [my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ4NN.png) looks very similar to yours.  I wonder if my compiler was doing some optimization like noticing that since `testData[i] == i` that `*testUnorderedSet.find(i)` must be equal to `i`.  In any case, I don't think this answer is correct.